# Pandas Column differences, containing lists

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where the columns values are list and want to find the differences between two columns, or in other words I want to find all the elements in column A which is not there in column B.

```
data={'NAME':['JOHN','MARY','CHARLIE'],
  'A':[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],
  'B':[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df[['NAME','A','B']]

#I'm able to concatenate
df['C']=df['A']+df['B']

    NAME    A   B   C
  0 JOHN    [1, 2, 3]   [2, 3, 4]   [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
  1 MARY    [2, 3, 4]   [3, 4, 5]   [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]
  2 CHARLIE [3, 4, 5]   [4, 5, 6]   [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

Any way to find the differences?

```
df['C']=df['A']-df['B']
```

I know we can use `df.apply` to a function but row by row processing will run slow since I have around 400K rows. I'm looking for a straight forward method like

```
df['C']=df['A']+df['B']
```

Comment: What do precisely do you want as a 'difference'? `df['A'].map(set) - df['B'].map(set)` would give a set difference.

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for! Can you add that as answer?
I was trying df['D']=set(df['A'])-set(df['B']), my bad!

Comment: Working for the above example but throwing memory error when I apply to a large data set!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a set difference,

```
df['A'].map(set) - df['B'].map(set)
```